# mcmc vs conjugate Bayesian analysis

Tags: bayesian, mcmc

I was planning to use MCMC to analyze a model, but decided to look at use conjugate pairs for my model to help speed up the calculation of the posterior.  I receive two different results and I was expecting these two solutions to be relatively similar assuming I ran sufficient samples in the MCMC simulation.  However I am noticing that in the conjugate pair model, the resulting posterior collapses to the likelihood estimate if I have a large number of samples in my my likelihood; regardless if my prior is well informed. This appears to be driven the number of samples in the likelihood when using the conjugate analysis  The MCMC model does not consider this.  What am I missing?

Consider the following:
both my likelihood and prior are assumed to be normally distributed

- likelihood mean: 2.0
- likelihood var: 0.25
- prior mean: 1.5
- prior var: 0.01

I am using the derivation of the posterior for conjugate analysis from Kevin Murphy.  Source to the paper is here: [https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/%7Emurphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf)

- Using MCMC, the posterior mean and variance are 1.514 and 0.0158
- Using conjugate pairs with likelihood samples n=2 the mean and variance are 1.537 and 0.0093
- But if I add more samples to the likelihood, n=100, the mean and variance are 1.9 and 0.002

Below are some graphs

[image]

[image]

Does this seem correct and why?  What am I missing?  I understand why the conjugate equations are pushing the posterior to be more centered around the likelihood - but I don't understand why this makes since, especially if I have a well informed prior.

Thanks